# Can't save my intellij projects in one folder

Tags: intellij-idea

At first, everything was working fine and all my projects were saved in the same folder. Suddenly, when I wanted to add another project, this message popped out.

[image]

Comment: The popped out message is in the picture uploaded

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another module in the same IDE project, use File | New | **Module...** action.

If you want to create a new separate project, it will not be possible to create it in the directory where you already have the existing IDE project (with existing `.idea` project configuration directory).

If you do need to create a project in same directory, you can then choose different **Module file location** and **Project location** when creating a new project - IDE will be using these directories for storing the module's `.iml` file and project `.idea` configuration directory:

[image]

The **Content root** here - is the location where you want to store your sources.

See [directory-based project format](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html#directory-based) for details.